# How to do a request in background each 5 minutes in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, background, background-process

I have an iOS application that communicate with an IoT gadget
And now I need a to do a request for an API each 5 minutes when the iOS app enters in background
I know this is horrible for battery consuming but in this specific case this is irrelevant since my iPhone device will always be connected to charger, and I won’t need this app in the store, so the apple politics is not a problem too

I already tried use Timer and TimerInterval, with the background state activated but none of then execute after the time I defined
Has any way to do this ?

Edit: I all my attempts I already activated background fetch, background music and all background modes

Comment: Have you tried utilising Background Modes? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uibackgroundmodes

Comment: You can abuse background audio to mode to play silence and keep your app running in the background

Answer (score 1):

First you need to start background mode in your project. It looks like this:[image]

To get to the background modes capability list you:

1. Select the project from the Project navigator.
2. Click the app target.
3. Select the Capabilities tab.
4. Turn the Background Modes switch on.

If you want to perform background task then select it from capability.

For more clarity for background fetch you can check below link
https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/background-fetch-ios-tutorial